# Socket.io - Preventing multiple connections from a client

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I just got started in node.js and created a server where browser clients can connect to it.

**Problem:** When there is an error in the nodejs server and it crashes and restarts, the connected clients will usually reconnect automatically, but I notice that many clients usually make multiple reconnections back to the server!

How can I prevent that from happening, either serverside or clientside?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest implementing it server-side. Apperantly, there is no implementation of it in socket.io ([Source Code](https://github.com/fantasticmf/node-socket.io-client/blob/master/socket.io.js)), so you can use key-value caches like Redis and map every connection in the Redis and check if user is already connected.